# Mysql KEY_BLOCK_SIZE value considerations in innodb COMPRESSED

Tags: mysql, compression, innodb

Trying to make sense of [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-compression-background.html) to determine the impact of KEY_BLOCK_SIZE in mysql innodb table with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

> As you specify smaller values for KEY_BLOCK_SIZE, you get the I/O
>   benefits of increasingly smaller pages. But if you specify a value
>   that is too small, there is additional overhead to reorganize the
>   pages when data values cannot be compressed enough to fit multiple
>   rows in each page.

Can someone elaborate what are the pros and cons of KEY_BLOCK_SIZE value of 1 vs 8, with some easy to relate to example? If my row size is going to be less than 1kb, will KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1 always give better IO? Will it matter if my key_block_size is going to be mostly less than 1kb. The statement "data values cannot be compressed enough to fit multiple rows" - how many rows is mulitple rows? Why it won't fit 1 row? I am even confused whether this relates to index size or actual row size.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `CREATE TABLE`; see how big a row needs to be.  If you make the blocks too small, you will hit another limit.

Keep in mind that InnoDB's `COMPRESSED` rarely gives more than a 2x shrinkage, and it costs a bunch to get it.

I don't have quite the answer you are looking for.  Instead, can we pursue the 'real' problem.  Is it disk footprint?  Is it I/O?  Is it some other performance metric?  There may be alternative solutions that work.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the queries.  Plus, describe the data somewhat.